# abc JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax-error, jsx, element

While building my react app I'm facing issues like this. I want to resolve the issue. I try to do some R&D but it did'nt work for me I need help to resolve this issue.

This error is facing in react-native file...

```
../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.tsx:35:8 - error TS2786: 'ScrollView' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'ScrollView' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/blocks/dashboard/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props

35       <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" style={styles.container}>
          ~~~~~~~~~~

../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.tsx:36:10 - error TS2786: 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/blocks/dashboard/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

36         <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.tsx:66:14 - error TS2786: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/blocks/dashboard/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

66             <View>
                ~~~~

../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.tsx:67:16 - error TS2786: 'Text' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Text' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/node_modules/@types/react-native/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/blocks/dashboard/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

67               <Text style={styles.body}>
                  ~~~~

../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.web.tsx:29:12 - error TS2786: 'Box' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | Component<...> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<BoxProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<BoxProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/blocks/dashboard/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
              Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

29           <Box sx={webStyle.mainWrapper}>
              ~~~

../blocks/visualanalytics/src/VisualAnalytics.web.tsx:34:14 - error TS2786: 'Box' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | Component<...> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<BoxProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
      Type 'Component<BoxProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.

34             <Box sx={webStyle.inputStyle}>
                ~~~


Found 619 errors.

npm ERR! Lifecycle script `compile` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: web@1.1.0 
npm ERR!   at location: /data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/web 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js build
Directory: /data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/insurancebroker-300102-react/src/packages/web
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
```

Package.json

---------------------

```
{
  "name": "visualanalytics",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose --coverage",
    "testBackend": "cd __tests__ && node endPointTest.js",
    "lint": "tsc && eslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}' --fix"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier-eslint --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "23.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.18.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.8.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-cucumber": "^2.0.11",
    "jest-enzyme": "7.1.2",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "10.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "5.0.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "reports",
    "reportFile": "test-reporter.xml",
    "indent": 4
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-native": "0.61.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsConfig": "__tests__/tsconfig.base.json"
      }
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js"
    ],
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    ],
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/coverage/",
      "endPointTest.js"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "!babel.config.js",
      "!node_modules/**/*",
      "!build/**",
      "!node_modules/**/**/*",
      "!coverage/**/*",
      "!__tests__/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to resolve issue by modifying package.json file using this lines.

"resolutions": {
"@types/react": "16.9.11",
"@types/react-dom": "16.9.11",
"@types/react-native": "0.61.3"
},

But This not worked for me!